# Combining three SQL statements into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have looked at combining two tables into one statement with SQL, but the examples I find online for combining 3 or more look to complicated for me to grasp...

I am looking to combine 3 statements into one, i believe it should be possible. 
Here is some pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve.

```
Select tagId from tags where tagName = "test"
->
Select photoId from photoTags where tagId = (tagId from previous statement)
->
Select * from pictures where id = (photoId from previous statement)
```

How can I combine this into one statement? I have a simple understanding of using JOIN but I don't understand multiple joins.

Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible as one statement?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct, I have edited my question. I meant NESTED Joins.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the pictures using such query:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM pictures p
    INNER JOIN photoTags pt on pt.photoId = p.id  -- Join tables pictures and photoTags
    INNER JOIN tags t on pt.tagId = t.tagId -- join tables photoTags and tags
WHERE t.tagName = "test"
```

It selects all columns from `pictures` table and filters the data by `tagName="test"`

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I was looking for. I simply added the where clause to the end of the statement to search by tagName.

Thank you, I still dont quiet understand where the "p." or "pt." is coming from although.

Comment: @JoshUnknown Yes, I forgot to add the `WHERE` clause, I updated the answer already

Comment: Correction it all makes sense now, its shorthand for the table names.
Thanks again!

Comment: @JoshUnknown I've always found writing `FROM pictures AS p` is more readable ("AS" is optional)

Comment: I like the idea of using AS, I also find it to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.TagId,PT.PhotoId,P.* FROM Tag T 
JOIN photoTags PT On PT.tagId =T.TagId
JOIN pictures P On P.Id=PT.PhotoId
WHERE T.TagName="test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM pictures p
    JOIN photoTags pt on pt.photoId = p.id 
    JOIN tags t on pt.tagId = t.tagId 
WHERE t.tagName = "test"
```